# Import-CliXML fails when called within a constrained session

Tags: powershell

**My scenario:**

1. I have a function that performs a privileged operation
2. This function requires access to a secret key
3. I need to run this function in a constraint PowerShell session (i.e. the function must run in a security context different from the user that invokes it)

**Here is how I attempted to implement a solution:**

1. I created a dedicated account that will provide RunAs credentials
       for a constrained PSSession.
2. I logged-in interactively as the service account and ran this command:

   ConvertTo-SecureString "MySecretKey....." -AsPlainText -Force | 
      Export-Clixml C:\PSScripts\panosAccessToken

This created a token encrypted for my service account.
 3. Inside the script that I am delegating, which will run in the context of the service account, I decrypt the key like so:

```
$accessToken = Import-Clixml C:\PSScripts\token
```

4. Next I register a PSSession, see details below.

**The Issue:**
When users connect to the session and attempt to run the function, the get the following error message:

```
[localhost]: PS> Get-PANOSBlockedTraffic
Import-Clixml : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'C' does not exist.
At line:4 char:20
+     $accessToken = Import-Clixml C:\PSScripts\token
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:String) [Import-Clixml], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportClixmlCommand
```

It appears that my function is not allowed to access the file system, despite the fact that the service account has the appropriate rights.
What am I missing?

```
 $getBlockedTraffic = {   
        $accessToken = Import-Clixml C:\PSScripts\token
        # The rest of the logic is removed to save space

    }

New-PSSessionConfigurationFile -Path c:\PSScripts\panos.pssc `
                               -Description 'PANOS Delegation EndPoint' `
                               -ExecutionPolicy Restricted `
                               -SessionType RestrictedRemoteServer `
                               -LanguageMode FullLanguage `
                               -FunctionDefinitions @{Name="Get-PANOSBlockedTraffic";ScriptBlock=$getBlockedTraffic; Options="AllScope"}

Unregister-pssessionconfiguration -name FirewallManagement -force
Test-PSSessionConfigurationFile -Path c:\PSScripts\panos.pssc

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "pwdHere" -AsPlainText -Force
$sessionCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("domain\user", $secpasswd)

Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Path 'c:\PSScripts\panos.pssc' `
                                -Name FirewallManagement `
                                -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI `
                                -RunAsCredential $sessionCreds `
                                -AccessMode Remote `
                                -Force
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constrained endpoint is using `RestrictedRemoteServer` which only allows access to a few selected cmdlets, and almost nothing else.

The `FileSystem` provider is not among the things allowed, so you aren't able to read from the filesystem.

You can allow just that provider:

```powershell
New-PSSessionConfigurationFile -Path c:\PSScripts\panos.pssc `
                               -Description 'PANOS Delegation EndPoint' `
                               -ExecutionPolicy Restricted `
                               -SessionType RestrictedRemoteServer `
                               -LanguageMode FullLanguage `
                               -VisibleProviders FileSystem `
                               -FunctionDefinitions @{Name="Get-PANOSBlockedTraffic";ScriptBlock=$getBlockedTraffic; Options="AllScope"}
```

By adding `-VisibleProviders` you can specify which providers are available to the session. Of course this allows all filesystem access now.